# Any way to push new version of WPF Application plus database changes (Sqlite) without using click once.

Tags: wpf, auto-update

I am working on a WPF application. I need an intelligent mechanism for updating my software and some other stuff such as database (My database is Sqlite) and application pre-requisites. Also, in my update I should be able to push application as  well as database changes. Click once wont suit my requirements. Whenever, a new version is available, I should be able to track it on application start and force the user to go for the new version only.

Answer (score 0):

Once an application is Compiled that is it. You can make you application Data Driven and this would work, however you will have to account for all the changes you need ahead of time. Why don't you do the following:

1. Create your WPF application
2. Create a WCF service that runs on your server.
3. Have you WPF application poll the WCF service to check if an update occurs
4. Have your WPF application download the new version off your server and force the user to update.
5. When the application reopens make it run the webupdate version and not run the old version.

Problem to think about:

- How do you want to handle if the user has no internet?

Comment: I was also thinking about the same process..however I would need to uninstall the old version and then install the new versions...One more ascept which I was thinking was just to push the dll which have been changed plus run some sqlite scripts for database changes.

Comment: Yes you would just give the dll's that change or are added and the executable.